# Proof of $\operatorname{arccot}(x)= \arctan(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification, inverse-function, fake-proofs

$\newcommand{\ac}{\operatorname{arccot}}$
Here is my proof:

$ \theta = \ac(x)$

$ \cot \theta = x $

$ \displaystyle \tan \theta = \frac{1}{\cot \theta} = \frac{1}{x}$

$ \displaystyle \theta = \arctan \frac{1}{x}$

But based on the graph, $\ac(x) = \arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ is only satisfied when $ x > 0$. What is wrong with my proof? What is the error occurred inside a proof?

Comment: domain of $cot^{-1}$ and $tan^{-1}\dots$

Comment: Are you saying the error lies in the difference of the domain of $cot^-1$ and $tan^-1$?

Comment: indeed, $arctan(-y)<0$ and $arccot(-1/y)>0$ for all $y>0$

Comment: There is no such restriction $x>0$.  The restriction is $x \ne 0.$

Comment: Please, let us see your graph.

Comment: @mjw https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGH29.png

Comment: Is it because in the above, $cot^-1(x) \in (0, \pi)$ but $tan^-1(\frac{1}{x})$ is only defined in the range $(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: yes, thats where the inequality in my previous comment comes from

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi, That's an arbitrary restriction of the range of $\cot^{-1} x$.

Comment: @mjw not an arbitrary restriction, but a principal value yes. Considering the intent of the OP, the principal value is to be considered

Comment: I guess that we can concede that $\cot^{-1} x = \tan^{-1} x + k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Using a figure of a right triangle, it is evident that for $0\lt \theta\lt \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ one has the proposed equality.

[image]

from which the equality is true for all $x\gt 0$.

However, for $x\lt0$ the equality is not true because, for example,

$$\operatorname{arccot}(-2)\approx2.6779\\\arctan(-\dfrac 12)\approx-1.1071$$

Comment: @Invisible:_ I am sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two conventions for principal value:

1. $\operatorname{arccot} x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ with a discontinuity at zero.
2. $\operatorname{arccot} x \in (0, \pi)$

See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html

It turns out that $\operatorname{arccot} x = \arctan(1/x)$ for all $x\ne 0$ for one convention of principal value.

If you want to adapt or enforce a particular range for $\operatorname{arccot} x$, then $\operatorname{arccot} x = \arctan(1/x) + k \pi$ for some integer $k$.

Here is what *Mathematica* thinks:

```
 Plot[{ArcTan[1/x] + .01, ArcCot[x]}, {x, -7 Pi, 0}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

You can rotate this second plot $90^\circ$ and define your range anyway you want up to a multiple of $\pi.$

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do I interpret this graph?

Comment: Added a legend.

Comment: Added $0.01$ to the $\tan^{-1}(1/x)$ curve to show that there are two curves there!

Comment: @ext_vayne The inverse function is multivalued outside the principal domain/range...so the cottangent and tangent overlap

Answer (score 0):

### Long comment:

The first problem with $$\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=\operatorname{arccot}(x)$$ is that $\arctan$ is an odd function, while $\operatorname{arccot}$ isn't.

Indeed, $\forall x\in\Bbb R$, the following holds:

$$\arctan(x)+\operatorname{arccot}(x)=\frac\pi2\implies\operatorname{arccot}(x)=\frac\pi2-\arctan(x)$$
Hence, if $x>0$, then
$$\arctan\left(\frac1{-x}\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=-\operatorname{arccot}(x)=-\operatorname{arccot}(-(-x))$$
and we cannot just move the sign under the argument. Therefore,
$$\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=\begin{cases}-\operatorname{arccot}(-x), &x<0\\\operatorname{arccot}(x),&x>0\end{cases}$$